# What's wrong with this simple code?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to compare the 2 arrays below and find the differences. The values for keys "lead owner" and "company" are different, but when I compare these arrays, it says only "company" values are different. But when I create 2 new arrays with only one key/value pair for "lead owner" it works properly. Am I making some mistake?

```
<?php

$arr1 = Array
    (
        "leadid" => "418176000000069007",
        "smownerid" => "418176000000047003",
        "lead owner" => "Amit Patil",
        "company" => "SAM",
        "first name" => "Test",
        "last name" =>"Lead1",
        "designation" => "call",
        "email" => "",
        "phone" => "958",
        "fax" => "",
        "mobile" => "",
        "website" => "www.infosys.con",
        "lead source" => "Cold Call",
        "lead status" => "Contact in Future",
        "industry" => "None",
        "no of employees" => "45000",
        "annual revenue" => "0",
        "rating" => "Active",
        "smcreatorid" => "418176000000047003",
        "created by" => "Amit Patil",
        "modifiedby" => "418176000000047003",
        "modified by" => "Amit Patil",
        "created time" => "2012-04-05 19:58:00",
        "modified time" => "2012-05-02 08:51:08",
        "street" => "",
        "city" => "",
        "state" => "",
        "zip code" => "",
        "country" => "",
        "description" => "",
        "skype id" => "",
        "email opt out" => "false",
        "salutation" => "Mr.",
        "secondary email" => ""
        );

$arr2 = Array
    (
        "leadid" => "418176000000069007",
        "smownerid" => "418176000000047003",
        "lead owner" => "Amit aaa",
        "company" => "SAM A",
        "first name" => "Test",
        "last name" => "Lead1",
        "designation" => "call",
        "email" => "",
        "phone" => "958",
        "fax" => "",
        "mobile" => "",
        "website" => "www.infosys.con",
        "lead_source" => "Cold Call",
        "lead_status" => "Contact in Future",
        "industry" => "None",
        "no_of_employees" => "45000",
        "annual_revenue" => "0",
        "rating" => "Active",
        "smcreatorid" => "418176000000047003",
        "created_by" => "Amit Patil",
        "modifiedby" => "418176000000047003",
        "modified_by" => "Amit Patil",
        "created_time" => "2012-04-05 19:58:00",
        "modified_time" => "2012-05-02 08:51:08",
        "street" => "",
        "city" => "",
        "state" => "",
        "zip_code" => "0",
        "country" => "",
        "description" => "",
        "skype_id" => "",
        "email_opt_out" => "false",
        "salutation" => "Mr.",
        "secondary_email" => ""
        );

$arr3 = array("lead owner" => "Amit Patil");
$arr4 = array("lead owner" => "Amit aaa");

print_r(array_diff($arr1,$arr2));
echo "<br>";
print_r(array_diff($arr3,$arr4));
?>
```

Output is as below

```
Array ( [company] => SAM )
Array ( [lead owner] => Amit Patil )
```

Comment: also add what is your desired output. means what you want the output to be?

Comment: in first line of output there should be "lead owner" key...which wasnt there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to diff between associative arrays so that the key-value pairs matter, not just the values, use [`array_diff_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php), not `array_diff`.

Comment: Its returning some wrong results, i mean its returning few columns that arent different ex: "no_of_employees","annual_revenue","created_by","created_time". Where values for this keys are exactly same. why this is happening ??

Comment: Looks like some of your keys are using spaces and some are using underscores.

Comment: try copying above code...there arent underscores. It also returns wrong result.

Comment: If you're talking about the code you posted in the question, I see, for example, "no of employees" in the first array, but "no_of_employees" in the second.

Comment: Opps my mistake, And yeah i think thats the problem, thats the common thing in all that columns. I will change it and will see if it works. Thanls for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are understanding it wrongly.

The documentation page of **[array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)** says

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not
>   present in any of the other arrays.

But the `Amit Patil` is present in the second array hence it is returning only one value which is `SAM` and It is only one value which is not present in second array.

Comment: Shakti, Thankns for this explanation, now i understand the difference between addta_diff() and array_diff_assoc()

Answer (score 1):

`array_diff()` returns complementary values. So you can do it like this:

```
   array_diff(array_merge($arr1, $arr2), array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
```

This way it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the "array_diff" function returns the values that occurs for any key in the first array and do not occurs for none of the keys in the second array.

The lead_owner "Amit Patil" is not equal to the second array lead_owner, but is equal to the created_by and modified_by keys of the second one.

You should use "array_diff_assoc" for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

try this and see, this should work

```
print_r(array_diff_assoc($arr1,$arr2));
echo "<br>";
print_r(array_diff_assoc($arr3,$arr4));
```